# ellipsoid or sphere in area calculations of terra?

Tags: cell, area, map-projections, terra

How the calculations of area are made in `terra`, when using geographical coordinates (lon/lat)?

1 - On a sphere or an ellipsoid?

2 - Using a constant width of the cells (the median width) as it was done in `raster` package, or using a more accurate algorithm?

My questions concern both the `expanse` and `cellSize` functions.

I tried to find the answers in the `terra` manual and the help pages, but I was not successful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to Robert Hijmans’ (@RobertHijmans) answer to this existing question ([Why do terra::cellSize() and raster::area() produce different estimates of raster cell area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68308376/why-do-terracellsize-and-rasterarea-produce-different-estimates-of-raste)):

> `raster` uses the product of the width (longitude) and height (latitude) of a cell. `terra` is more precise, it computes the spherical area of a cell (as defined by its four corners). This matters most at high latitudes, where the width of a cell changes most, and can be different between the bottom and the top of a cell. So the difference will be largest at high latitudes and with cells with a low vertical resolution.”

Dr. Hijmans also says:

> "The bigger change in `terra` is that it also computes actual cell-size for projected (i.e. not lon-lat) rasters."

See the existing question linked above for examples from his answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> On a sphere or an ellipsoid?

The WGS84 ellipsoid

> Using a constant width of the cells or a more accurate algorithm?

More accurate. See Christopher Crawford's answer